# Why is my .link specification ignored?

Tags: debian, networking, udev

I want to activate persistent network names on Debian 9.13 Stretch to prepare for an upgrade to Debian 10. I am following the instructions on https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames#custom. I produced three link files in /etc/systemd/network with a contents of

```
MACAddress=00:0d:b9:37:ee:04

[Link]
Name=lan0
```

added, the new interfaces allowing hot plugging in the interfaces file and rebuilt my initial ramdisk.

However, the rule is seen, but ignored. With  udevadm info /sys/class/net/eth0 I get

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0x8168
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=r8169
E: ID_NET_LINK_FILE=/etc/systemd/network/10-persistent-net.link
E: ID_NET_NAME=lan0
E: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx000db937ee04
E: ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp1s0
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=PC Engines GmbH
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:01:00.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_01_00_0
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Ethernet controller
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0x10ec
E: IFINDEX=2
E: INTERFACE=eth0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/eth0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5086233
```

and the used interface name still is eth0, as before.

What am I doing wrong?